# OnePlus mobile Issue not responding on media call

Tags: css, oneplus6t

Can somebody help me why the simplest code for paragraph is not responding on media call for oneplus phone.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:479px),only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.625) {
    .pinfo {
        color:#333333;
        line-height:98%;
        text-align:left;
        font-size:16px;
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation I've seen says the device pixel ratio is 'about' 2.625 so if it comes in at very slightly under then your media query will fail. Can you try a lower number, say 2.5, and see what happens then if it works gradually increase it?

Comment: I did tried it, it didn't work. I already figured it out, Its one table on top of my code that's affecting everything, seems like a table doesn't have a good responsiveness on oneplus phone. thanks